# Angular 2 debugging issues

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm

I'm starting out on a sizeable angular 2 project and am having a lot of difficulty debugging. I am using Angular-CLI, WebStorm and Chrome.

Whenever I run into an issue, firstly my IDE fails to catch any problems with the typescript. No matter the issue, the browser *always* shows this error about 15 times, could be because of a syntax error in my code, injecting incorrectly, constructor problems, or markup issues.

```
    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
    at NoProviderError.set [as stack] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6147:61)
    at assignAll (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:98290:29)
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:98361:16)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6109:16)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58296:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58345:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79884:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79921:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79871:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79633:21)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59199:52)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80642:45)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81070:49)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80150:27)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79918:24)
```

How am I supposed to figure out the issue from this error message? Is there a tool to help understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same error, the details of the error mentioned above can be seen by upgrading zone.js version in package.json to ^0.7.4(anything greater than version 0.7.4).
You can also upgrade by this npm terminal command:

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4
```

Other than this I use the Intellij (JetBrains), angular-cli and chrome and debugging goes quite easy.

Comment: Oh my god this is so much better

Comment: It actually gives me a variable name now!